# Adding fields of two DataSets in a Tablix rdlc

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, rdlc

I have made two DataSets named as LedgerDetails & LedgerDetailsOB.
LedgerDetailsOB contains following field

```
Account_Code | Open_Bal | C_D
```

LedgerDetails contains :

```
Account_Code | Date | Description | Amount
```

For Now I made relationship with Account_Code in DataSource thought if it would work but not working.

I passed a **parameter to Account_Code** to the report and fetching the data from Stored Procedure using the parameter. And it works correct...

Now I want like first data from LedgerDetailsOB shows up, when it finishes, the data from LedgerDetails continues from the very next line in the same table.

The Things I did is : 
The first row is the headers of the tablix and 2nd row is the data from LedgerDetailsOB.
Made the 3rd row and tried to add the data from LedgerDetails but it will deny for sure...

I searched and found LOOKUP function written as expression so I did the same..
Following expression I tried to run in the 3rd row of the tablix:

```
=LOOKUP(Fields!Account_code.Value,Fields!Account_code.Value,Fields!Trans_Date.Value, "LedgerDetails")
```

And the expression above show no error line(red line) in the expression box.

After then, I clean the project and rebuild it so I get the following error.

> The Value expression for the text box ‘Account_code’ refers to the
>   field ‘Account_code’.  Report item expressions can only refer to
>   fields within the current dataset scope or, if inside an aggregate,
>   the specified dataset scope. Letters in the names of fields must use
>   the correct case.

Note: This is a subreport/childreport i am working in.. Just for Information..

Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a view using the SQL below:

```
SELECT
    OB.account_code,
    OB.open_bal,
    OB.C_D,
    DT.date,
    DT.description,
    DT.amount
FROM
    LedgerDetails AS DT,
    LedgerDetailsOB AS OB
WHERE
    OB.account_code = DT.account_code
```

Answer (score 0):

The tablix can refer only to one data source. The easy solution is to "flatten" you data and combine it into single `DataSet` with the following fields:

```
Account_Code | Date | Description | Amount | Open_Bal | C_D
```

Then you can group your rows by account code and date and there won't be any need for lookup.

Comment: So if we refer link, they used two datasets into a single Tablix, how they did that??? I can give you the link where I found... And even this option will work but not good option...

Comment: I'm not sure what link you are referring to. It's not clear why this would not work for you.